# ng-repeat / ng-src on slider angular materialize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, slider

i try to make a slider with angular-materialize, reading http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/, they tell just to put the slider code in the div, and it'll call directive from the angular-materialize.js.

home.html:

```
<div class="slider fullscreen z-depth-1" slider>
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <img src="assets/img/illustration/parsprototo/ppt2.jpg"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="assets/img/illustration/kenmeri/kenmeri_marker.jpg"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="assets/img/illustration/bagua/BG1.jpg"></img>
    </li>
</ul>
```

working perfectly.

now i want to try the ng-repeat and take the data from JSON by using ng-src, and its not working, just gray color background.

home.html with ng-repeat and ng src

```
<div class="slider fullscreen z-depth-1" slider>
    <ul class="slides">

        <li ng-repeat="slide in slidesData">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}"></img>
        </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

not working.

controller.js

```
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);
appControllers.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http){
        $http.get('assets/json/home.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.slidesData = data;
        });
    }
]);
```

home.json

```
[
    {
        "image" : "assets/img/illustration/mudra/mudra1.jpg",
        "headingText" : "This is our big Tagline! 1",
        "sloganText" : "Here's our small slogan."
    },
    {
        "image" : "assets/img/illustration/parsprototo/ppt2.jpg",
        "headingText" : "This is our big Tagline! 2",
        "sloganText" : "Here's our small slogan."
    },
    {
        "image" : "assets/img/illustration/kenmeri/kenmeri_marker.jpg",
        "headingText" : "This is our big Tagline! 3",
        "sloganText" : "Here's our small slogan."
    },
    {
        "image" : "assets/img/illustration/bagua/BG1.jpg",
        "headingText" : "This is our big Tagline! 3",
        "sloganText" : "Here's our small slogan."
    }
]
```

what could be wrong? Thanks before.

**EDIT**

new controller.js

```
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);
appControllers.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log'  ,
    function ($scope, $http, $log){
        $http.get('assets/json/home.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.slidesData = data;
            $scope.$log = $scope.slidesData ;
        });
    }
]);
```

i modify the controller.js to write the json on $scope.slidesData if it's loaded, but nothing written in my console. :(

no error either.

**EDIT**

console worked as i change to `console.log($scope.slidesData)`

[the console looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzSK6.png)

Comment: Any errors in console ? and could you log your `$scope.slidesData` and check whether you are getting data in it ?

Comment: @Achu I'll already edit the post, i log it to the console, and nothing in it. Is it my code for log are wrong or it's something else??

Comment: Instead doing `$scope.$log` try doing `console.log($scope.slidesData)` and open your developer window (F12) and check what is displaying over there.

Comment: @Achu thanks, the console works. it shows [object,object,object,etc] as I edit on my question. I don't know if its success or not. now what should I do?